# Log In Problem In Sharepoint Site

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory, authentication

We are facing Login problems while Logging to our site.  We (the Developement Team) can log in to the site with only one prompt but many users are getting login prompts several times. After pressing ESC for 5-6 times they can login to site.  Is there any AD setting that needs to be changed?

If so not even the Site Admin (Full Permission) can log in without prompts.

I have already added the site in trusted sites in Internet Explorer.

Comment: I edited the two comments you posted as answers into your question.  You should add additional information to the question itself, or as a comment, not as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a publishing site? If so, have you ensured that all of your content is published? If anything is still in draft and has never been published then they will receive authentication prompts as ordinary users can't see draft content. Make sure you check CSS files and other assets such as images.

Answer (score 0):

Add your site to the Trusted Sites in Internet Explorer

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check out [this link here](http://www.pptspaces.com/sharepointreporterblog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=28) and check your settings compared to these. I have set up several MOSS 2007 servers following this guide with no problems at all...except for small mistakes on my part :P